# Getting text to display to the left and right of a text-align: center

Tags: html, css

Alright so I have

```
    <div id='1'></div>
    <div id='2'></div>
    <div id='3'></div>
```

Only one word will go into each div. I want the width of each div to be auto

and I want to word from #2 to be in the middle of the screen using text-align: center; with the word in #1 being displayed directly to the left of #2 and the #3 directly to the right of #2.

I have been trying different css for a while, but to no effect.

Hoping someone has a simple answer.

Comment: Did anyone properly answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Simply float all the divs to the left. They will display in order.

```
<style>
  .my-dvis {
    float:left;
    width:33.33%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:none;
  }
</style>

<div class="my-divs"></div>

<div class="my-divs"></div>

<div class="my-divs"></div>
```

Comment: I would also add the ID tags and do the text justification.

Comment: doesnt work as Id like it http://codepen.io/jakeschievink/pen/dxfsH I want the first and last divs to be right after the word in the middle

Comment: No, I want to text from the first and last divs to be directly before and after the text in the middle, not stuck to the right and left sides of the screen.

Comment: @invot it appears as I would like it, but whenever you add characters to the words in the codepen, it does not display properly, so if you changed the word "two" to "pleasant" then it make a newline.

Answer (score 1):

`text-align: center` only applies to inline elements.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dM5rT/)

#### HTML

```
<div class="left">1</div>
<div class="middle">2</div>
<div class="right">3</div>
```

#### CSS

```
body { text-align: center; }

div { display: inline-block; }
```

Comment: This is close, but I want the width to be dependent on the size of the word displayed, not on a percentage. when I set the width to auto in your example, it breaks.

Comment: what's the problem with this solution?

Comment: @gp what I mentioned above, and if the word is long, it overflows past the width defined in the .middle instead of centering, and having .right displayed directly to the right of .middle

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried floating id=1 to the left and floating id=3 to the right?

Comment: doesnt work as Id like it http://codepen.io/jakeschievink/pen/dxfsH I want the first and last divs to be right after the word in the middle

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `<span>` tag instead of using `div` tag,because `div` have a property of taking `width 100%`.

Or else if you want to use div tag then use in the following manor

```
<div id='1'></div>
<div id='2'></div>
<div id='3'></div>
<style>
div{
float:left;
width:33.3%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: This does not display the words as described. I want the word in #1 to be directly to the left of the word in #2. This displays #1 at the leftmost area of the screen.